# How to Replace an object in Pandas array using replace with dictionary from excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, preprocessing

Suppose I have a data like this:

[image]

and I want to change the value of name and gender into an integer, and I have a dictionary like this:

[image]

I understand that I can use replace function in pandas, but I don't know how to use an excel dictionary to replace the value

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a pair of csv files: "replace.csv" representing the first table and "table.csv" representing the second table i.e. "dict". Use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.read_csv('replace.csv')
table = pd.read_csv('table.csv', header=None)

mapping = dict([(k, v) for k, v in table.values])

frame.replace(to_replace={"name": mapping, "gender": mapping}, inplace=True)
print frame
```

The line `mapping = dict([(k, v) for k, v in table.values])` is the one that transforms your dataframe into a dict. For more on transforming a dataframe into a dictionary see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695605/python-pandas-dataframe-to-dictionary) provides different ways of transforming a dataframe into a dictionary. For reading excel files, instead of csv files, see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).